# How to create a button that will increase its width depending on the amount of text in it?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I have a WPF window with a button on it. I want the button to increase or decrease in width depending on its text. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you set the text dynamically?

Comment: Yes, it's set dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `Width` property to `Auto` and give an HorizontalAlignment (`Center`, `Right`or `Left`), because its default value is `Stretch`, and this cause to *Fill* its container.

Here is an example on how it works:

**CODE**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Content="A Default Button"/>
        <Button Content="An Auto Width Button" 
                Width="Auto" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="An Auto Width and Height Button" 
                Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I you don^t set a fixed width to your button, it will already adapt its width to its content.